# Koalas data frame pivot_table with row and column totals

Tags: pandas, pivot

I have previously used the following code on a Pandas dataframe to successfully generate a pivot table containing both column and row totals like in Excel:

```
df_check=df.pivot_table(index=['month_yr'], columns=['product'], margins=True, aggfunc=np.sum, values='weight', margins_name='Total')
```

I am now working with the same data as a **Koalas dataframe** in Databricks.  However this code will not run; I cannot use `'margins=True'` or `'margins_name='Total'` since these produce errors.

I modified the above code to run but without column/row totals:

```
kdf_check=kdf.pivot_table(index=['month_yr'], columns='product', aggfunc='sum',values='weight')
```

How do you modify this code to add row and column totals?

From kdf.head().to_dict():

```
{'city_nm': {0: 'HAMILTON',
  1: 'MADAWASKA',
  2: 'PALMER RAPIDS',
  3: 'OXFORD MILLS',
  4: 'MADAWASKA'},
 'prov': {0: 'ON', 1: 'ON', 2: 'ON', 3: 'ON', 4: 'ON'},
 'dest_country': {0: 'United States',
  1: 'United States',
  2: 'United States',
  3: 'United States',
  4: 'United States'},
 'commodity_descrp': {0: 'BIOLOGICAL SUBSTANCE',
  1: 'VME CARD CAGE/HEAD. SENSOR SENT',
  2: 'DENTAL IMPRESSION TRAY',
  3: 'LAPTOP',
  4: 'VME CARD CAGE/HEAD. SENSOR SENT'},
 'harmonized_code': {0: '3002.90.5010', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''},
 'acct_nbr': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''},
 'bus_nm': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},
 'naic_4_cd': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''},
 'product': {0: 'FAST', 1: 'FAST', 2: 'SLOW', 3: 'FAST', 4: 'FAST'},
 'weight': {0: 11.0, 1: 85.0, 2: 0.7, 3: 7.0, 4: 85.0},
 'dest_indicator': {0: 'US', 1: 'US', 2: 'US', 3: 'US', 4: 'US'},
 'mth_yr': {0: 'July2020',
  1: 'May2020',
  2: 'June2020',
  3: 'December2020',
  4: 'May2020'},
 'hc_dig': {0: '30', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''},
 'hc_dig_clean': {0: '30', 1: '', 2: '30', 3: '', 4: ''}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [**`koalas.pivot_table()`**](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) doesn't support `margins`, I would just add the totals manually:

```py
kdf_check = kdf_check.append(kdf_check.sum().rename('Total'))
kdf_check['Total'] = kdf_check.sum(1)

# product        FAST  SLOW  Total
# mth_yr                          
# December2020    7.0   NaN    7.0
# July2020       11.0   NaN   11.0
# June2020        NaN   0.7    0.7
# May2020       170.0   NaN  170.0
# Total         188.0   0.7  188.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your code makes sense but I am getting this message: 
ValueError: DataFrames.append() does not support appending Series to DataFrames.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @jackhomareau huh odd, i guess koalas deviates quite a bit from pandas. try starting from a fresh `kdf_check` and appending with this instead: `kdf_check = kdf_check.append(kdf_check.sum().rename('Total').to_frame().T)`